# complex polynomials and inequalities

Tags: cv.complex-variables, inequalities, elementary-proofs

Let $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n\in\Bbb{C}$ be distinct and $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n\in\Bbb{C}$ be arbitrary. Suppose $f, g$ are two polynomials of degree less than $n$ such that
$$f(z_j)=w_j,\qquad g(z_j)=\bar{w}_j \qquad\text{for $1\leq j\leq n$}.$$
Define $\Omega(z)=\prod_{j=1}^n(z-z_j)$. The following puzzles me.

> **Question 1.** Is this true?
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\vert f^{\prime}(z_k)\vert^2}{\vert \Omega^{\prime}(z_k)\vert^2}\leq
> \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\vert g^{\prime}(z_k)\vert^2}{\vert\Omega^{\prime}(z_k)\vert^2}.$$

**EDIT.** I'm sorry, one of the conditions was missing. To give credit, I'll leave the question as it stands and ask the correct one below.

> **Question 2.** What if we insist that $f$ and $g$ have equal degrees?

Comment: Any further background where's this coming from? thanks.

Comment: It was a technical need that occurred in some Monge-Ampere equations.

Comment: I am puzzled. Polynomials $\ f\ g\ $ appear in a symmetric way. Then why inequality and not equality? Indeed, if the theorem held for all $\ f\ g\ $ then there would be equality.

Comment: Yes, it would be equality indeed. It's implied.

Comment: Well $f,g$ are uniquely defined by interpolation given the $z_j$'s and $w_j$'s, so $f=\bar{g}$ necessarily...

Comment: @PhilippeNadeau: it's not as easy as that; the $w_i$ are replaced by their complex conjugates but not the $z_i$, so the change in coefficients is a bit more mysterious.

Comment: Indeed, I wrote too quickly this morning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $n\ge 3$, let's take  $z_j$,  for   $1\le j\le n$, be the $n$-th roots of unity, and $w_j:=z_j+4\bar{z_j}$, so that the assumption are satisfied by $$f(z):=z+4z^{n-1}$$ $$g(z):=4z+z^{n-1}.$$ However, 
$$  |g'(z_k)|=|4+(n-1)  z_k^{-2}|  \le n+3<\phantom{Z} $$ $$ \phantom{ZZZZ} <4n-5\le|1+4(n-1)  z_k^{-2}|= |f'(z_k)| $$ for any index $k$ in the sums.

**Rmk.** For $n=2$, $f$ and $g$ are affine functions, with $|f'|=|g'|={|w_1-w_2|\over |z_1-z_2|}$, so that the claim is true.

Comment: Modified to fit question 2 (the customer is always right)

Comment: That was funny, Pietro!

Answer (score 1):

This Matlab program shows that your conjecture is in general not true for $n\geq 3$

```
n = 3;

z = rand(1, n) + 1i * rand(1, n)
w = rand(1, n) + 1i * rand(1, n)

f = polyfit(z, w, n-1);
g = polyfit(z, conj(w), n - 1);

% note that Omega(z_i) = 0 and Omega(z) = z^n+q(z) where deg(q)<=n-1 and
% hence q(z_i)=-z_i^n
Omega = [1 -polyfit(z, z.^n, n - 1)];

df = polyder(f);
dg = polyder(g);
dOmega = polyder(Omega);

adf = abs(polyval(df, z));
adg = abs(polyval(dg, z));
adO = abs(polyval(dOmega, z));

sum((adf./adO).^2)-sum((adg./adO).^2)
```

Comment: I don't use mathlab. Do you mind giving the specific complex numbers that generate the example?

Comment: Pasting this into the Matlab console a couple of times gives a positive final value (11.1599) for `z = [0.8143 + 0.3500i,  0.2435 + 0.1966i,   0.9293 + 0.2511i]`, `w =  [0.6160 + 0.8308i,   0.4733 + 0.5853i,   0.3517 + 0.5497i]`